# Dublin Core HTML5 W3C Validation

Tags: html, w3c-validation, dublin-core

I'm trying to use Dublin Core with HTML5, when I try to validate the code with W3C validator I got a error.

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="schema.dcterms" href="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">
    <meta name="dc.language" content="en">
    <meta name="dc.title" content="web site title" /> 
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Error Line 5, Column 62: Bad value schema.dcterms for attribute rel on element link: The string schema.dcterms is not a registered keyword.

Error Line 7, Column 51: Bad value dc.title for attribute name on element meta: Keyword dc.title is not registered.

Using the W3C Validator: http://validator.w3.org/check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `meta` keyword `dc.language` is [registered](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions#Registered_Extensions): **valid**.

The link type `schema.dcterms` is [registered](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values#Dublin_Core), however, not in the "HTML5 link type extensions" section (so it doesn’t confirm to the [requirements](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/links.html#other-link-types) described in the HTML5 spec): so it’s, strictly speaking, **invalid**.

The `meta` keyword `dc.title` is [not](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions#Registered_Extensions) registered: **invalid**.

You might want to use `dcterms.title` instead. (By the way, the keyword `dcterms.language` is also registered.)